# how would I produce 2 random integers, and then compare them?

Tags: java

I want to produce 2 different random integers using java.util.random. then want to compare those two numbers, for example the code produces 5 and 9. then if one number is bigger than the other, use conditional operators to put the bigger number into variable var1. end result "9 is the bigger number". this is all I have starting out.

```
 Random rand = new Random();

   
    int n = rand.nextInt(50);
    n += 1;
    System.out.println(n);
```

do I have to create n1 and n2 or can I produce 2 random numbers from the same variable?

Comment: short answer: `do I have to create n1 and n2` - yes

Comment: Variables store _values_, not formulae for "producing" values.  The only thing an `int` variable can "produce" is whatever `int` value was most recently assigned to it.

Comment: Why do you have the line ``n += 1;``?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why do you even want to do this that way, but you can do it like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int var1 = Math.max(rand.nextInt(50), rand.nextInt(50));
System.out.println(var1 + " is the bigger number");
```